# pdfplumber to handle pdf online

Tags: python, pdf, url

I am trying to handle the online pdf file by pdfplumber. But it seems pdfplumber can't support urlopen, and it only supports pdfplumber.open to process local pdf files.

Any solutions?

```
fp = pdfplumber.open("t1.PDF")
#fp = pdfplumber.urlopen('https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/sehk/2020/0124/2020012400942_c.pdf')
```

Comment: So download the file first. Even if it would appear to work with "online" files, that's exactly what it would be doing in the background.

Comment: thanks, it is a good and easy way.

Answer (score 3):

The repo of **pdfplumber** is [here](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber). You do not have to download the pdf if you just need to process the pdf file. You can access the link directly as below:

```
import urllib3
import pdfplumber
import io

def extract_text_from_pdf_by_url(url):
    all_text = ''

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    temp = io.BytesIO()
    temp.write(http.request("GET", url).data)
    try:    # to verify is the url has valid pdf file!
        pdf = pdfplumber.open(temp)
        for pdf_page in pdf.pages:
            single_page_text = pdf_page.extract_text()
            # TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
            if single_page_text is not None: 
                all_text += '\n' + single_page_text
        pdf.close()
    except:
        pass
    return all_text


url  = 'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/sehk/2020/0124/2020012400942_c.pdf'
text = extract_text_from_pdf_by_url(url)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pdfplumber` does not natively support downloading PDF files from the web but you can download the PDF first and then load it in `pdfplumber`. Example

```py
from io import BytesIO

import requests
import pdfplumber

req = requests.get("https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/sehk/2020/0124/2020012400942_c.pdf")

with pdfplumber.load(BytesIO(req.content)) as pdf:
    print(pdf.pages[0].extract_text())
```